# Regex to apply to everything except a folder

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression for an URL so that it affects everything except a certain folder. The regex will only apply to everything after the '/', so given an url the url `http://www.blah.com/folder/main/file.html`, it will apply only to `folder/main/file.html` - the regex expression I want is the expression that will basically match always when there is no '`folder/`' in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead. For example this:

```
^(.(?!folder/))*$
```

will match anything which does not contain 'folder/'

Comment: its for the IIS rewrite rules.... I tried putting \/ - that didn't work either....